# ssis read text file network share

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Apparently inside of an SSIS script task, StreamReader does not work over a network share.

Dim streamReader As New StreamReader("\myserver\c$\myfile.txt")

Any workarounds?

Comment: Why dont you use a flat file connection instead?

Comment: Do you have an error message? It could be permissions. Have you tried using a share rather than the administrative share I.E. `"\\MyServer\Share\MyFile.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a File System Task and copy the file to your local machine to say C:\FileDropbox and then have the script run against this file and delete the file after the script has run.